# Create a variable based on another in R

Tags: r

In R Studio, I would like to add a column which is "percentage of maximum load" (see on the pictures), based on the relative load in the same line, and the highest four-line value in the load column. Here the maximum should be "115" in the 
data.

[image: Data]

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well, you could simply do something like that:

```
data$Percentage <- data$Load / max(data$Load)
```

Comment: Thanks ! In fact, I would like to create it considering the id.